# wxpython csv reader crashing while processing

Tags: python, csv, wxpython

I have built a csv reader with. It iterats through a file and gives results based on search terms.   I am reading 3 gig files.  When I let it iterate through the file it works fine.  But if I even touch the wxpython window after processing has begun the app stops responding then crashes.  My best guess is I have to somehow monitor/throttle cpu usage.  I have no idea how to do this or if I am on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a long running process which blocks wx's main loop. That's why it's unresponsive. You'll want to put the long running process into a separate thread that sends updates to the GUI from time to time. See the following articles for various approaches:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Answer (score 1):

During a heavy operation a wx frame is "stuck" waiting on the process to finish. You're best solution is to create a worker thread and let it do the heavy job for you.